# Postfix sending html email without defining the mime-type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postfix-mta

In a rails app when sending out emails on my development machine the html emails look as expected when viewed, in that both the html and plain text can been seen nested in the proper mimetype when the raw version of the email is viewed, while the html renders properly when viewed normally.

The live server behaves differently. Only the html is sent and the mime type is not defined, which results in the email displaying a lot of html.

I am running up to date versions of archlinux on both the server and my dev machine, with postfix also running on each machine as the mail server.

Any ideas of what could be causing this difference?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be running vagrant and puppet/chef. Then you can find out.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with each of the tools mentioned, but after doing a little searching it seems that they allow for install scripts. If that is the case I am not sure how that would help.  I should mention that postfix was installed on each of the machines with a simple `pacman -S postfix` command, and there were no additional configuration tweaks done on either of the servers.

Comment: There obviously is some configuration difference. The tools help you triangulate fast and find the relevant difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried restarting the postfix daemon, but that didn't seem to help.  Once traffic died down I restarted the server and things worked.  There were never any changes made to any of the configuration settings and doing a diff between my local settings and the remote showed no differences.

So I don't have the slightest clue to why things were behaving the way they were.